# expected file 'file_path' but didn't (Zeitwerk::NameError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redmine, redmine-plugins, zeitwerk

with the transition to Redmine 5 (uses Rails 6.1.7.4.), I'm trying to adapt the code of a custom plugin. I currently have this file in `redmine_lutech_integration` directory:

```ruby
#redmine5/plugins/redmine_lutech_integration/lib/redmine_lutech_integration/catalogue_user_format.rb 

module Redmine   
  module FieldFormat     
    class CatalogueUserFormat < RecordList        
      #do stuff     
    end   
  end 
end
  
Redmine::FieldFormat.add 'job', Redmine::FieldFormat::CatalogueUserFormat
```

This works without issues with the classic code loader, but with Zeitwerk I get:
`expected file redmine5/plugins/redmine_lutech_integration/lib/redmine_lutech_integration/catalogue_user_format.rb to define constant RedmineLutechIntegration::CatalogueUserFormat, but didn't (Zeitwerk::NameError)`

`RecordList is a class included in field_format.rb file located in Redmine5/lib/redmine/field_format.rb`

Is there something wrong with the file structure or am I missing something in the Zeitwerk settings?

For similar issues regarding other files in the same plugin but that they didn't need FiledFormat or other things, I have resolved them by adding
`require File.dirname(__FILE__)+ 'path'` to the plugin's init file.

Answer (score 1):

About first error

For `Redmine::FieldFormat::CatalogueUserFormat` you should create such file:

```rb
# redmine5/plugins/redmine_lutech_integration/lib/redmine/field_format/catalogue_user_format.rb
#                                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

module Redmine   
  module FieldFormat     
    class CatalogueUserFormat < RecordList        
      #do stuff     
    end   
  end 
end
```

It is standard Ruby convention: `Namespace::ClassOrModuleName` should be defined in the `namespace/class_or_module_name.rb`, `CONSTANT_NAME` in the `constant_name.rb`

---

About second error

`require File.dirname(__FILE__)+ 'path'` — probably `path` is local variable, not literal `path` string